# Is there a way to store XML.appendChild function in a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, e4x

I want to use something like that:

```
var addFunction:Function = needParentNode ? parentNode.appendChild: resultArray.push;

for each(var element:* in elements){
    addFunction(element);
}
```

But `parentNode` is `XML`, so `parentNode.appendChild` returns an `XMLList` because of E4X syntax. `parentNode['appendChild']` is the same.
I know that i can get a wrapper with

```
function(item:*){parentNode.appendChild(item)}
```

**But is there a way way to get this function without such complications?**

Comment: What do you mean by "returns an `XMLList` " ? According to docs `appendChild` returns `XML` : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html

Comment: What the OP is saying is that `parentNode.appendChild` without the parenthesis denoting it as a function call will resolve the same as the statement `parentNode['appendChild']` which will return an `XMLList` of any children named "appendChild".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
parentNode.AS3::appendChild
```

Specifying namespace might help.

Comment: Thanks, that really works! So happy to see it because I expected the issue to be impossible to solve.

Comment: I am happy that you are happy :')